# Want to write a trigger for update and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 3 tables:

1. item (id, itemname)
2. stock(stockid, stockquantity, itemid)
3. sale (saleid, salenumber, itemid)

So I have to write a trigger in such way that if a sale of any number of item is inserted than it automatically updates the stockquantity column in the stock table. And that it will minus the previous stockqty record and update it.

Comment: Help with what? First we need to see the code you've written, then we need to know what the problem is.

Comment: Are there multiple rows in the `stock` table for the same `itemid`? If so, how do we know which row to update? If not, why is it separate from the `item` table? Are stock quantities adjusted upwards in an adhoc fashion or is there another table recording inbound deliveries? If the former, it seems fragile - how do you know it's accurate? If the latter, why store it at all when SUM(deliveries) - SUM(sales) should always tell you the current quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple trigger for your idea :

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourInserttriggername ON Sale 
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE stock
    SET StockQuantity = StockQuantity + SUM(Inserted.SaleNumber)
    FROM Inserted 
    WHERE Stock.ItemId = Inserted.ItemId
    GROUP BY Inserted.ItemId
END   


CREATE TRIGGER YourUpdatetriggername ON Sale 
AFTER Update
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE stock
    SET StockQuantity = StockQuantity + SUM(Inserted.SaleNumber - Deleted.SaleNumber)
    FROM Inserted 
    INNER JOIN Deleted ON Deleted.Id = Inserted.Id
    WHERE Stock.ItemId = Inserted.ItemId
    GROUP BY Inserted.ItemId
END


CREATE TRIGGER YourUpdatetriggername ON Sale 
AFTER Delete
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE stock
    SET StockQuantity = StockQuantity - SUM(Deleted.SaleNumber)
    FROM Deleted 
    WHERE Stock.ItemId = Deleted.ItemId
    GROUP BY Deleted.ItemID
END
```

Comment: Considering that `inserted` and `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows, those `UPDATE`s all look particularly risky. See [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177523.aspx): "The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated"

Comment: Also, for your `DELETE` trigger, you reference `inserted` in the `WHERE` clause but it's not in the `FROM` (and of course, would contain no rows) and you single trigger faces a similar issue, even after you realise you need to switch from `INNER` to `FULL OUTER` and correct the `NULL` issues.

Comment: Still not sure given that the OP hasn't answered whether there might be multiple rows in `stock` with the same `ItemId` - the given table descriptions suggests that this may be possible, in which case the problem is still woefully underspecified.